# Android: Keep data for the activity, create same activity in 5 different instances

Tags: android, savestate

I have an android application with 2 activities and the first one is a TableView holding 5 items generated by the code not in xml. In xml its only one TableLayout with an id thats it, ok.

I wonder how i can keep data within an activity.

Scenario:

1. Click on a row in the tableView opens up a new activity with a lot of data.
2. Hitting back button will directly destroy the activity and NOT run onSaveInstanceState so my data is lost.
3. When hitting the "same" row again, the activity is recreated!

So my questions has two:

i ) How to not destroying all the data from the second activity? Have tried things like onSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceState / onCreate and so on, always empty and destroyed!

ii ) Is it possible to startActivity and have a "uniq" instance of the activity for each row in the table? So the thing here is every row in the table will right now start a new activity of the second activity and I don't want every row to use "same" activity, do I need to create 5 different exactly the same activity with different data or?

Hope you understand my questions?

Comment: Sounds like you need fragments.

Comment: Sounds like he needs to use persistent storage

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood you want to save instance of activity B when you are coming back to Activity A. So that you can start Activity B again on same state. This wouldn't be possible as on back press finish() method of current activity is called.

A simple solution of this comes to my mind is, onBackPressed of Activity B you can update a bundle(this will be present on Activity A unique for every row) against current state of your Activity B. Next time when you open Activity B send this bundle with it and in onCreate of Activity B handle this bundle to show last saved instance of current activity. Through this you can use same activity for every row. Don't have to make copy of same activity multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try! But how to get the bundle when Activity A want rerun onCreate, not even the Activity B will be rerun onCreate, neither the onRestoreInstanceState will be run in any of these ones!?

Comment: Welcome :)
For Activity A it wouldn't but for Activity B it will call onCreate every time. If you are using startActivtiy().

Comment: Ok But if Activity A not rerunning how to retrieve the bundle set then ?

Comment: I maybe solved this one in another way by creating the Activity B each time!